# What does proprietary trading for derivatives mean?

Tags: trading

I understand traditional asset management is buying/selling stocks with clients' money to generate alpha, and proprietary trading is using the company's own money instead.

For derivatives, do proprietary desks exist as well, separate from the investment bank desks? This would mean three separate desks dealing with derivatives - asset management (for hedging), investment banks, and proprietary desks.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: yes there are prop shops that trade derivatives. they are not really at banks anymore due to the Volcker rule.

Comment: So the 3 desks you mention are actually at different companies: an Investment Bank (e.g. GS), an Asset Management company or division (e.g. GSAM), and a hedge fund or partnership (for proprietary trading). They are not side by side in the same organization.

Comment: Proprietary trading used to be at the Broker/Dealers.  This desk would take risks using the Broker/Dealers capital.  This is distinct from the Broker/Dealer trading at the firm, which is to facilitate market making and client trading activities.  As there are inherent conflicts of interest, the desk would be walled off from the other parts of the business--no information and communication was allowed to be passed from the dealer desk to the prop desk and vice versa.

Comment: Volcker regulations killed off the proprietary trading business for banks. For European banks, other regulations made it very expensive in terms of regulatory capital, eg. recent exits from prop trading by BNP and SG. Indepent proprietary shops trading derivatives is not that common I think, except places using Futures to gain exposure to equities. Some specialized funds might focus on arbitraging in complex derivatives, eg. CDO correlation before the crisis.